# Writing Unit Tests for TSX (TypeScript for JSX/React) for the Browser

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, typescript, tsx

I have been researching a good workflow for developing React based components in TypeScript.

Since 1.6, TypeScript has native support for JSX in TypeScript files through the `.tsx` extension and with `tsd` we can get IDE (atom/WebStorm) to support type checking.

However, there does not appear to be an easy way to test React components written in `tsx`.

Can you share your insights on this?

I am considering (almost obliged to use) `Jest` as opposed to pure `Jasmine` because `Jest`'s runtime environment comes with a DOM. However, jest appears to only work with ES2015 through `babel` and `es2015, react` presets. Is there a readily available way for `Jest` to work with `tsx`?

Currently, I can test React components written in ES2015 like:

```
// SampleComponent.js

import React from 'react';

class SampleComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (<div className='container'>Hello World!</div>);
  }
}

module.exports = SampleComponent;
```

and the corresponding test might look like:

```
// __tests__/SampleComponent-test.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';

const SampleComponent = require('../SampleComponent');

describe('SampleComponent', ()=>{
  it("has some text", ()=>{

    const result = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
      <SampleComponent />
    );

    const sampleComponentNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(result);

    // expect statements

  });
});
```

this works fine, but if we replace the `.js` extension with `.tsx`, and change the `scriptPreprocessor` to be:

```
'use strict';

var ts = require('typescript');

module.exports = {
  process: function(src, path) {
    if (path.match(/\.(ts|tsx)$/) && !path.match(/\.d\.ts$/)) {
      return ts.transpile(src, {jsx: ts.JsxEmit.React, module: ts.ModuleKind.CommonJS});
    }
    return src;
  },
};
```

All hell breaks loose, especially with regard to the way TypeScript handle module loading

Comment: Do you really need a `scriptPreprocessor`? You might also want to share what's the exact error you're getting.

Comment: To be honest I could be over complicating things. But the error messages I am receiving are along the lines of "React is undefined" due to the fact that my compiled `js` files are not always using the same `module` paradigm as the libraries that are being used.

Comment: Can you try compiling all your files (including test files) with `tsc -p .` and then run the generated js files instead?

Comment: What is the best module format to compile the TypeScript files to? For example, if we compile it to `systemjs` or `commonjs` and if the test has dependency on external libraries like `react` or `angular` then we need to write boiler plate just to load these dependency. I was wondering if there a way to not have to do that ... probably not, but its a long shot.

Comment: I tend to use `commonjs` but I mostly work with nodejs. You can use whatever suites your needs. They're (almost) all the same to me.

Comment: I also use webpack to avoid that headache, but I've never written UI tests with it. Give it a try and see. :)

Comment: webpack looks promising, I will explore! thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After exploring, I've come to a tentative solution that works well especially if your project integrates `react` with other frameworks.

This solution does need elaborate module loading boilerplate (which I dread for front-only projects). I think this approach will last until ES6 module loading becomes standard.

## Tentative Solution

#### Test Runner

karma

#### Browser

phantomjs (so it can be readily available in CI servers)

#### Engine

jasmine

#### Transpiler

tsc with `--jsx react` or  `{"jsx": "react"}` in `tsconfig.json`

#### To Test with Libraries (e.g. angular-mocks)

Load them in `karma2.conf.js` like so:

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        // bind-polyfill helps phantomjs acquire the Function.prototype.bind function
        './node_modules/phantomjs-polyfill/bind-polyfill.js',
        "bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "bower_components/angular/angular.js",
        "bower_components/react/react-with-addons.js",
        "bower_components/react/react-dom.js",
        "bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js",
        'src/**/*.js'
    ],
```

#### Compile All TS files to ES5, Do Not `export` Symbols

By not exporting symbols from `.ts` and `.tsx` files, the compiled `js` files can be simply loaded through `karma2.conf.js` as seen above.

#### Why phantomjs?

It has a DOM and allows you to render and manipulate `react` components.
Facebook's own testing framework: `Jest` provide the same benefits (as some others).

#### Downside

Since `karma` uses a browser and files are loaded in ways similar to a traditional web site, it might be difficult loading code mean't for the backend (i.e. not available through Bower). For example, instead of using `react` `TestUtils` I was forced to use jQuery + real DOM provided by Phantom.

#### Production

As Louy mentioned in the comments, webpack or any one of the standard task runners could be used